# Drawing over green pixels only on a canvas image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-video

i'm capturing a video frame to a canvas using

```
var video = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var outputcanvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
outputcanvas.width = 640;
outputcanvas.height = 480;
var ctx = outputcanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,640,480);
```

I then have some black and white drawings on mycanvas that i want to draw over the video frame, however i want to avoid drawing over any blues.

Does anyone know of a way i can manipulate the image on my canvas and place it over the video frame I have just added?

I have alpha set, so only the drawings themselves are placed onto the outputcanvas using:

```
ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,640,480);
```

any ideas?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you're looking to do, but maybe this can help: Could you grab the canvas' image data (massive array of all pixel RGBA values) using its context, and then iterate over this data checking if every RGBA value is "close enough" to green, and if so grabbing to image data at the same indexes from your "overlay image" and swapping them out for the ones on the canvas? Maybe this could be a viable solution.

Comment: i could give it a try, the only issue i can see is i'm doing this inside 
 requestAnimationFrame in realtime so I'm not sure what the performance impact would be but can try.  Many thanks, i'll post what happens :-)

Comment: Cool! As far as I know, getting and setting pixels by directly manipulating the pixel buffer is very fast in this case. However I can't guarantee that the logic behind "checking to see if it's close enough to green" will be all that fast. Best of luck. :)